# crawler based on Scrapy fails in login in a website

Tags: python, scrapy

I use two methods to login in a website. The method based on **Scrapy** fails, while the method using **urllib2** is successful.  I am just confused on why the first method fails, which I do as the tutorial.

Method based on **Scrapy**. The return page is just the login page. I set cooike enable in setting.py.

```
class AccountSpider(InitSpider):
    name = "counting"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    login_page = 'https://www.domain.com/login.aspx?code=1'
    start_urls = ["https://www.domain.com/Search/Search.aspx"]
    rules = ()

    def start_requests(self):
        return self.init_request()

    def init_request(self):
        print 'login init'
        return [Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)]

    def login(self, response):
        print 'login ing'
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'__VIEWSTATE':'/+a_fix_string',
                '__EVENTVALIDATION':'/+a_fix_string',
                    'username':'username',
                    'password':'password',
                    'EnableAutoLogin':'on',
                    'LoginButton.x':'24',
                    'LoginButton.y':'9'},
                callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self,response):
        # check if login successfully
        if 'Welcome' in response.body:
            print 'login in successfully'
        else:
            print 'login in failed'

    def parse_item(self, response)：
        pass
```

Method based on **urllib2**. Login in successfully.

```
def login():
    cookie_support= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar())
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    postdata=urllib.urlencode({
        '__VIEWSTATE':'/+a_fix_string',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION':'/+a_fix_string',
        'username':'username',
        'password':'password',
        'EnableAutoLogin':'on',
        'LoginButton.x':'24',
        'LoginButton.y':'9'
    })

    agent = {
         'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like                  Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31'
        }
    req = urllib2.Request(
        url='https://www.domian.com/login.aspx?code=1',
        data = postdata,
        headers = agent
    )

    result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return result


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        login()
```

Comment: have you checked `FormRequest.from_response(...).url`? are there different forms in the page? Have you also tried setting the User-Agent via `headers={"User-Agent":....}`?

Comment: I set the "USER_AGENT" in settings.py.   The return FormRequest.from_response(...).url is different from login page url.

Comment: You should check `formname` to select the correct form, and/or use `.replace(url=self.login_page)` to force the URL you want it sent to. Also check [`dont_click=True/False`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response)

Comment: The response.url of FormRequest.from_response(response,...) is right.  The url of return FormRequest.from_response(response,...) is different. I add "dont_click=True", but it does not work.  I don't understand the meaning of "formname" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html, FormRequest object should be put into list comprehension. Example from the documentation:

```
return [FormRequest(url="http://www.example.com/post/action",
                formdata={'name': 'John Doe', 'age': '27'},
                callback=self.after_post)]
```